# QImage in a QGraphics scene

Tags: qt, qimage, qgraphicsscene

I am quite new to Qt. I am having troubles in inserting a `QImage` to a scene. Could somebody please tell me how to add a `QImage` to a `QGraphicsScene`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this you would use a [`QGraphicsPixmapItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html) that you [add to the scene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem) like any other `QGraphicsItem`.

The `QGraphicsPixmapItem` can be initialized with a `QPixmap` which is a device-dependent representation of a bitmap and you can get it from a `QImage` for example with the static function [`QPixmap::fromImage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fromImage).

**Update (example code)**

```
#include <QtGlobal>

#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    #include <QtWidgets>
#else
    #include <QtGui>
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QImage image("test.png");

    QGraphicsPixmapItem item( QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->addItem(&item);

    QGraphicsView view(scene);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but it was not working for me. I have pasted my code below.

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but it was not working for me. I have pasted my code below.

         QGraphicsScene scene;
         QImage* qimage = new QImage("./IMG_2938.JPG");
         QGraphicsPixmapItem pixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(*qimage));
         scene.addItem(&pixmapItem);
         QGraphicsView view(&scene);
         view.show();

It doesn't show the image, just a window, but it just shows an emptybox.Hope someone can answer.

Comment: I added some example code to my answer. This works for me (it is very close to what you posted). So two things come to mind: 1. Are you sure the image is found and loaded correctly? (check QImage::isNull() or use QImage::load() explictly and check the return value) 2. If you put objects on the stack instead of the heap, make sure they are still alive when they are used.

Comment: The code in the example will not work after the function containing `item` returns, because `item` is destructed upon returning.

Comment: `error: variable 'QGraphicsPixmapItem item' has initializer but incomplete type
     QGraphicsPixmapItem item( QPixmap::fromImage(image));`

Comment: The example was written for Qt4; I assume you are using Qt5 where the widgets got split of into their own module. I changed the example to compile for both cases.

Comment: wouldn't the addPixmap() function of QGraphicsScene work?

Answer (score 2):

As @Neal suggested, addPixmap works much simpler and where the QGraphicsPixmapItem would not work for me for some unknown reason. Assuming you have a `QGraphicsScene`, `QGraphicView` and rest of program set up the below code will just display the image:

```
QString filename = "C:/image.png";
QImage image(fileName);
scene->addPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```