# Qt Not displaying PNG on QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qpixmap

Please note: I am a Qt newbie.

**Purpose:** 
I am attempting to display a PNG on a GraphicsView object on a UI form

**Tried:** 
I have been following a [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960074/qimage-in-a-qgraphics-scene), from this post, for displaying a PNG, but have had no luck.

My PNG does not display onto a GraphicsView object on my UI. My GraphicsView size is (w 121,h 111) and my png size is (w 100,h 100).

Headers/mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsView *view;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Sources/main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Sources/mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    view = ui->graphicsView;
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(view);
    view->setScene(scene);
    QPixmap pixmap("back.png");
    scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
    view->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Forms/mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>283</width>
    <height>415</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>250</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Login</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Remeber Me</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>59</width>
      <height>14</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Email</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>59</width>
      <height>14</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Password</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>96</x>
      <y>310</y>
      <width>80</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Register</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>283</width>
     <height>19</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

PNG location, root directory

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

note 1: fixed png location error, but that did not solve the issue. Must be something else.

to clarify root directory

Project is in `VPN` directory

```
$ ll /home/cx/qt-projects/VPN/

total 48
drwxrwxr-x 1 cx cx   162 Oct  5 15:45 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 cx cx    90 Oct  5 12:21 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx  1514 Oct  5 15:33 back.png
drwxrwxr-x 1 cx cx   108 Oct  5 12:12 .git/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx   172 Oct  5 10:41 main.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx   393 Oct  5 15:45 mainwindow.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx   399 Oct  5 15:25 mainwindow.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx  3134 Oct  5 12:21 mainwindow.ui
drwxrwxr-x 1 cx cx     8 Oct  5 12:11 res/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx   400 Oct  5 12:12 VPN.pro
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx 24064 Oct  5 12:35 VPN.pro.user
```

Thus refering to image location below works:

```
QPixmap pixmap("/home/cx/qt-projects/VPN/back.png");
```

but this does not, why?

```
QPixmap pixmap("back.png");
```

Comment: Does "back.png" exist in the file system?  You state "PNG location, root directory" but the path being used is relative (and I'm assuming you're not running from the root directory).

Comment: @G.M. THanks, I just noticed this now, implemented the change, but did not fix this issue. So there must be an error somewhere else too...

Comment: I don't think you fix file location. Try **full** path to file to be sure that no error here.

Comment: How do you build your project? PNG are loaded through plugins: are they installed where you're executing your code?

Comment: @KonstantinT. I will try full path, see if this helps, although it is cause for concern in later projects if only full path works

Comment: Do you really mean "root" directory (as in "/") -- or are you referring to your project's root directory?

Comment: @wasthishelpful please clarify, what do you mean by "how do you build your project" and where can I check for said PNG plugins?

Comment: @G.M. I mean project root, see update

Comment: @KonstantinT. I jsut attempted full path, it works, am I refering to project root incorrectly?

Comment: If you want use `QPixmap pixmap("back.png");` you need put `back.png` to your **working directory** look in `Projects=>Run=>Working directory:` it can differ from *Project root* directory.

Comment: @KonstantinT. oh, my workign directory is /home/cx/qt-projects/build-VPN-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Debug. Interesting, thanks for the help! I am looking into using the resource system to store my png rather

Comment: Using resources is safer as long as you do not have to change back.png often because in that case you would have to recompile binary